# Compute Shader OpenGL Write to Texture

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I want to write to a texture with a compute shader. for testing purposes i only want to write blue pixels to a given empty texture.
I am only getting a black screen.
I will show the relevant part of my code

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos; 
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoords;

out vec2 TexCoords;

void main()
{
   TexCoords = aTexCoords;
   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragement Shader

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D screenTexture;

void main()
{
    vec3 col = texture(screenTexture, TexCoords).rgb;
    FragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
}
```

Compilation Compute Shader (all used variables are members of my class)
//Update as Rabbid76 suggested, still not working

```
cshader = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER);
const char *csSrc[] = {
    "#version 440\n",
    "layout (binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform image2D destTex;\
     layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16, local_size_z = 1) in;\
     void main() {\
           ivec2 storePos = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);\
           imageStore(destTex, storePos, vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0));\
    }"
};
glShaderSource(cshader, 2, csSrc, NULL);
glCompileShader(cshader);
cshaderprogram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(cshaderprogram, cshader);
glLinkProgram(cshaderprogram);
```

Creating Output Texture

```
glGenTextures(1, &this->outputTexture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->outputTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, width(), height(), 0, GL_RGBA32F, 
GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glBindImageTexture(0, this->outputTexture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, 
GL_RGBA32F);
```

Drawing on Quad

```
glUseProgram(cshaderprogram);
glUniform1i(0, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindImageTexture(0, outputTexture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, 
GL_RGBA32F);
glDispatchCompute(width() / 16, height() / 16, 1);

glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT);

screenProgram.bind();
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(screenVao);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, outputTexture);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

I hope you guys can help me. if there are questions just ask them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your compute shader does not even compile, because it consists of 2 strings:

```
const char *csSrc[] = {

    "#version 440\n",

    "layout (binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform image2D destTex;\
    layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16, local_size_z = 1) in;\
    void main() {\
        ivec2 storePos = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);\
        imageStore(destTex, storePos, vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0));\
    }"
};
```

You have to attach both string to the shader object to solve the issue:

```
glShaderSource(cshader, 2, csSrc, NULL); // <--- 2 instead of 1
```

I recommend to use [Raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
const char *csSrc[] = {

    "#version 440",

    R"(
    layout (binding = 0, rgba32f) uniform image2D destTex;
    layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16, local_size_z = 1) in;

    void main() {

        ivec2 storePos = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
        imageStore(destTex, storePos, vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0));
    })"
};
```

Use [`glGetShaderiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShader.xhtml) to check for compile errors:

```
GLuint cshader = glCreateShader( GL_COMPUTE_SHADER );
glShaderSource(cshader, 2, csSrc, NULL);
glCompileShader(cshader);
GLint compile_status;
glGetShaderiv( cshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_status );
if ( compile_status == GL_FALSE )
{
    GLint maxLen;
    glGetShaderiv( cshader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLen );
    std::vector< char >log( maxLen );
    GLsizei len;
    glGetShaderInfoLog( cshader, maxLen, &len, log.data() );
    std::cout << "compile error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
}
```

And use [`glGetProgramiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgram.xhtml) to check for link errors:

```
GLuint cshaderprogram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(cshaderprogram, cshader);
glLinkProgram(cshaderprogram);
GLint link_status;
glGetProgramiv( cshaderprogram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &link_status );
if ( link_status == GL_FALSE )
{
    GLint maxLen;
    glGetProgramiv( cshaderprogram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLen );
    std::vector< char >log( maxLen );
    GLsizei len;
    glGetProgramInfoLog( cshaderprogram, maxLen, &len, log.data() );
    std::cout  << "link error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
}
```

---

Further note, that `GL_RGBA32F` is not a proper *format* parameter for [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml). While the *internalFormat* parameter specify the format of the target texture on the GPU, *format* and *type* (together) specify the format of the source texture. Use `GL_RGBA` instead of `GL_RGBA32F`:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, cx, cy, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```